# Show Multiple Data in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am new in android. I want to show the data that I get from `Database` into `ListView`.

For now I can show only a single data.
How to show multiple data into custom `ListView`?

Here's my **MainActivity.class**

```
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    /**
     * CRUD Operations
     * */
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts.."); 
    List <AllItem> allItems = new ArrayList<AllItem>();

    allItems = db.getAllAccommodations();

    ArrayList <String> allItems2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (AllItem cn : allItems) {
        allItems2.add(cn.getItem_name());
        allItems2.add(cn.getAreaNAme());

    }

    ArrayAdapter <String>  adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,allItems2);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have my own custom `ListView` like this

**Acco.xml**

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listAccommodation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:divider="@color/black90"
        android:dividerHeight="5.0sp"
        android:listSelector="@color/black30" >

    </ListView>
```

**AccoLayout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/area_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_name" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Your best bet is to use a Cursor Adapter, you dont have to loof through

Comment: @Matthew take a look here I have described in detail how to show the multiple records from database into a listview...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520702/show-data-sqlite-in-textview/25521480#25521480

Comment: @ByzantineFailure Do you have any link for nice example or tutorial? I ever try using Cursor Adapter, but I can't get it how to use it.

Comment: You want to show allItems list and allItems2 list in a listview whose each line is a layout of two text fields, right? If so, I may help with this with a custom adapter.

Comment: @FarukYazıcı I just want to show the `allItems2` in `ListView`.
Can you really help me? Just a simple one is ok.

Comment: @Darkie So I have to create a new class do handle the Adapter? Then  call it in my MainActivity class?

Comment: But why do you have two text fields in AccoLayout.xml? If one of them will hold the related item in allItems2, what data will the other one hold?

Comment: @FarukYazıcı There're multiple data. Like Item name and areaname. I use allItems2 to convert the data into String from allItems so I can show it in `ListView`

Comment: @Matthew yes you have to handle the adapter separately ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your allItems2 list has a pattern like itemName0, areaName0, itemName1, areaName1, itemName2.. etc. Then, you can write a custom adapter like this.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final List<String> items;

public CustomAdapter (Activity context, List<String> items) {


    super(context, R.layout.AccoLayout, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items= items;

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.AccoLayout, null, true);

    TextView itemName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    TextView areaName= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.area_name);


    itemName.setText(items.get(2*position));
    areaName.setText(items.get(2*position + 1));

    return rowView;
}
```

}

Then call it from your main activity;

```
CustopAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter (MainActivity.this, allItems2);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also, by Android's convention, try not to use uppercase letters in XML file names to prevent any complication. You may change to acco_layout.xml.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Faruk Yazici. It work. But, what if I have more thatn 2 column? For the example `itemname, areaname, address, price`. Am I just have to use (2*position + 2), etc ?

Comment: No, if you have three values, they will be (3*pos), (3*pos + 1), (3*pos + 2)
And if you have four columns (4*pos), (4*pos + 1), (4*pos + 2), (4*pos + 3)

Comment: Yes, I just got it after try it :D

Comment: But i suggest you use a list of objects. It will be much more tidy and you will reach each item only by one position index :)

Comment: Thanks @FarukYazıcı , i've used this custom class and it works brlliantly. However, I am getting a fatal error `Invalid index 6 , length is 6`. When debugging, all values are as expected and indexes seem correct in `items.get(2 * position +1));` etc etc . Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create CustomAdapter class for this.
Use your listview as it is.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listAccommodation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:divider="@color/black90"
    android:dividerHeight="5.0sp"
    android:listSelector="@color/black30" >

</ListView>
```

And your custom Listview also.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:paddingTop="10dip"
android:paddingBottom="10dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/area_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_name" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Create your custom adapter class and pass data to this class.

```
adapter = new ListAdapter(this, allItems2);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is CustomAdapter class.

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {



public ListAdapter(Activity a, List <AllItem> allItems) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;      
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.AccoLayout, null);
  TextView itemName = (TextView)vi.findviewById(R.id.item_name);
  TextView areaName = (TextView)vi.findviewById(R.id.area_name);
        // Set your data here
  itenName.setText(data.get(position));//like this
    return vi;
}
```

}

Comment: hi @Sandip, I got an error on `ListAdapter` like activity cannot be resolved to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this to be your Cursor: after you fetch from DB

```
Cursor mCur = db.getAllAccommodations();
```

in onCreate:

```
CurAdapter Cur = new CurAdapter(getActivity(), mCur,0); 
    final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listAccommodation); 
    lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    lv.setAdapter(Cur);
```

Then Make a Subclass:

```
private class CurAdapter extends CursorAdapter{


        public CurAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {

            super(context, c, flags);


        }


        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.area_name);




            String item = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ColumnName1")));

            String area = dateConvert(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ColumnName2")));



            tv1.setText(item);
            tv.setText(area);

        } 
        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.AccoLayout, null);

            return view;

        }

    }
```

Where R.layout.AccoLayout is your "listview row" layout, for example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/area_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_name"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The Subclass is use for handle the custom adapter?

Comment: The Subclass will handle your looping and everything!

Comment: Sorry if I ask too much. Ok, I'll try it. Thanks for your answer :D